# How do i remove anti-alias (bitmap font) in cs5 TLF text

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs5, tlf

How can i use a bitmap text (no anti-alias at all), i can't find that option , the same option that exists in the classic text field.

Answer (score 0):

You should embed you own **font** with such properties.